# How do I disable Shutter plugins?

Tags: plugins, screenshot, shutter

Shutter is a nice software but it takes a while to load. I observed that initially it loads some plugins (eg:upload-plugin). Is there a way to disable these plugins so that shutter loads quickly?

please illustrate how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initialization of plugins should only appear once (e.g. after updating Shutter or a fresh install of Ubuntu). If this dialogue appears every time you start Shutter it is simply a bug. 
There is an updated version of Shutter in our PPA. Please give it a try to see if it is fixed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install shutter
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. However, now it gives following warning in terminal
WARNING: Net::DBus::GLib is missing --> Ubuntu One support will be disabled!

WARNING: Image::ExifTool is missing --> writing Exif information will be disabled!

Comment: Solved it using `sudo apt-get install libnet-dbus-glib-perl libimage-exif-perl`

Comment: Many thanks, @Romario, for the PPA hint. This does solve the problem. Are you thinking of removing defunct upload sites like ubuntu-pics?

Comment: @izx: Sure, I am already working on it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. My screen is stuck at "Updating upload plugin information." I want to disable plugins (and really, anything automatic / that uses the Internet), per the question.

Comment: BTW, in general, I hate apt-adding repos, as eventually they will fail, and cause my `apt-get update` to throw errors.

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing weird behavior, where I'd try to start `shutter` and I'd get a screen saying, **Updating upload plugin information**. And that screen would just sit there for 1-2 minutes.

Trying to start `shutter` from the commandline, it was outputting messages about `/usr/share/shutter/resources/system/upload_plugins/upload/vgyme.pm`

So I tried simply getting rid of that `upload` directory (moving it to a backup location, just in case):

```
sudo mv /usr/share/shutter/resources/system/upload_plugins/upload ~/backup_upload
```

I then rebooted (which I think was the core of my problems), and now starting `shutter` works just fine. So whether they were the problem or not, I think I'll happily leave those plugins out.

Comment: This is a good solution. Works for me on Manjaro as well. I've just removed the upload directory `sudo rm /usr/share/shutter/resources/system/upload_plugins/upload`. The update message is appearing because it fails to "compile" some of the upload plugins.

Comment: The same solution worked. Got it every freaking time I tried to take a screenshot. I'm in Endeavor (Arch). My path was /usr/share/shutter/resources/system/upload_plugins/upload based on the console output.