# How to disable shutter plugin updates?

Tags: shutter

Time to time `shutter` tries to update its plugins and I don't need it. How to turn off these unwanted updates?

Comment: I came here to ask exactly this. If I open shutter, it's because I need to make a screengrab *now*.

Comment: For anybody who still interested in this, check out https://askubuntu.com/a/1226831/1305645. works for me!